# Combination of two convolution filters

Tags: matlab, convolution

What is one filter matrix equivalent to applying [1 1 1] twice on an image using imfilter with parameter 'full'?  Would it still be a 1x3 matrix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

convolution is associative, which means `(f*g)*h = f*(g*h)`. So instead of

```
r = conv(conv(x, [1,1,1]), [1,1,1])
```

you can precompute the convolution of the two filters and then apply it to each image only once:

```
tmp_filter = conv([1,1,1], [1,1,1]);
...
r1 = conv(x1, tmp_filter)
r2 = conv(x2, tmp_filter)
```

where the new filter is `[1 2 3 2 1]`, which however is not of the same size of the original filter.

Comment: Ah gotcha! why 1 2 3 2 1 and not 0 2 3 2 0? Thanks!

Comment: well, if you figure it graphically the `1`s are when only the extremities overlap, the `2`s are when two elements overlap and the `3` is when the functions completely overlap

Comment: Unless you use the `same` parameter, which returns an output with the same size of the first parameter, which gives you `[2,3,2]` (which is equivalent to `[0,2,3,2,0]`).

Comment: Note that if you use `same` when convolving the two kernels, the resulting kernel is not equivalent to the composition of the two kernels. You need to use `full` when composing kernels. This is true independently of what mode is used to apply the convolutions to the image.

Answer (score -1):

The `full` parameter tells the `filter` function to return an image of the same size of the filtered image.  You can apply the same filter any amount of times, but if you use `full` every time, the size should not change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering though, instead of convolving twice with [1 1 1], what convolution filter can we use just once?

Comment: This is wrong. `full` causes the output to be larger than the input. `same` preserves the size. Also, this answer doesn’t address the question.